# how to apply defer function in my following model.py file to lazy load fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Event(
OwnedModelMixin,
TimeStampedModelMixin,
RandomIDMixin,
models.Model,
 ):
    after_sunset = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shabbos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    starts = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)
    community = models.ForeignKey(Community, blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
    """
    Returns a reprsenative fields depending on the event type

    """
    child_events = (
        'bar_mitzvah',
        'bar_mitzvah_kiddush',
        'bris',
        'kiddush',
        'shalom_zochor',
        'vachnacht',
    )
    if self.event_type in child_events:

        return '{} on {},is_published: {}'.format(
            self.event_type,
            self.date,
            self.is_published
        )
    else:

        return '{} on {},is_published: {}'.format(
            self.event_type,
            self.date,
            self.is_published
        )
```

There are almost 160 attributes which I have not included in it.But all the attributes are not needed all time. I want to lazy load those attributes to improve the performance.As there are 160 attributes and there are 1000 rows.How can I?

Comment: There's definitely something wrong with your model structure if you have 160 fields.

Comment: It's pre-build application. I have been assigned a task to improve its performace.

Comment: But automatically lazy loading is the wrong thing to do. For a start you should be thinking of splitting up the model so that some fields are in other models related via FK or OneToOne. And second you should think about which fields actually need to be stored, rather than calculated - for example whether something is after sunset or on "shabbos" can be calculated from the date/time.

Comment: Ya I agree. But using defer how can I achieve it because I have been told to do with same.

Comment: I am beginner so need help in this as I am instructed to do it with defer else only function .